# Conversion of .SLDDRW(solidworks) into .IGES (.IGS)

Tags: file-format, cad, solidworks

How to save SolidWorks **2D** drownings (.SLDDRW) into IGES file.
I know how to conwert **3D** drownings, but in **2D** there is no IGES in *Save As*.
Should be some way because at the begining IGES was created for **2D**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IGES can be exported only from part or assemblies. I'd suggest the following workaround:

1. Save a drawing in DXF/DWG format.
2. Open saved DXF/DWG file.
3. In DXF/DWG Import dialog select radio button 'Import to a new part as' and either option under it.
4. Press Finish button. A new part or assembly should be created.
5. Now you can export in IGES format. Just make sure that in IGES Export options 'IGES wireframe (3D curves)' is checked.

Good luck!